# Meaning and Usage of "comma" and "claimed"

Tags: ambiguity, legalese

*Subject to the other provisions of this Act, the State Commission shall have jurisdiction—
(a) to entertain—
(i) complaints where the value of the goods or services and compensation, if any, claimed
exceeds rupees twenty lakhs but does not exceed rupees one crore;*

The above is an excerpt from an enactment (The Consumer Protection Act, 1986) of India.  Is the expression, "claimed" applicable to "value of goods or services and compensation, if any," or only to "compensation, if any,"?

**My question, rephrased, using some numbers:** Assuming "Value of goods or services" is 70 lakhs, "Value of goods or services **claimed** is 25 lakhs" and "compensation **claimed** is 5 lakhs", would it mean 25 + 5 lakhs or 70 + 5 lakhs?

**Note 1:** one crore = 100 lakhs.

**Note 2:** This is more a question in English usage and its meaning than interpretation of a legal provision but I tagged it as 'legalese' because the source of the text is from an enactment.

Comment: If the commission has jurisdiction over claims, they want to know the amount of the claim, right? They might compare it to the market value, but the claim (written in the complaint) must fit in the 25-100 range. Don't worry, a bureaucrat will check the complaint for that amount, and the commission will see those that fit, only.

Comment: This is indeed legalese, and I don't believe that general English usage will help at all: the interpretation of this sort of thing is a specialist task of lawyers. In ordinary English, FWIW, _claimed_ must apply to both, because otherwise _value of goods or services_ has no role in the sentence; but who knows what the lawyers will make of it?

Comment: I find *rupees twenty lakhs* and *rupees one crore* to sound very strange. It sounds like *I have dollars 20*, which, although not actually wrong, is still bizarre.

Comment: That aside, assuming I were looking at a normal English sentence, *if any* is inside parenthetical commas, and it has no bearing on the syntax of the surrounding text. Replace the commas with actual parentheses or remove *if any* altogether and look at the sentence again. That, however, still doesn't help, because the combination of ***or*** and ***and*** in the sentence makes the list items ambiguous, thereby also making the referent of *claimed* ambiguous. There is simply no way of telling with certainty what the referent of *claimed* is with the sentence as it's written.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about "legalese", not "normal English"

Comment: I don't think it's that specific. the amount of compensation awarded is a matter for the commission to decide. This extract says that the commission has juristriction over claims where the value of the goods and services together with any compensation claimed over and above the value of the goods (perhaps for wasted time) is greater than 20 lahks but is no more than 100 lakhs. In other words they have no juristiction under this paragraph over claims outside that range. However this is paragraph a)i) so there will be at least one other category over which they have juristiction.

Comment: When any of the expressions are not given any special meaning within an enactment, it is the plain English meaning that is used.  This is similar to what we do when we speak/write about other domains.  So, though the source is an enactment, I am only concerned with how the English is understood or is to be understood.

1 mil. = 10 Lakh. 1 USD = 75.15 INR (rupees)

Sincerely appreciate your time and input. I now think "claimed" has to apply to both otherwise 'value of goods or services' has no place if compensation claimed is zero.

@FumbleFingers: you may close this question as answered

Comment: I cast my closevote when I posted that comment, but it's only 1 of the 5 required from "ordinary" (non-moderator) users such as myself to actually close the question. Actually, I'm not convinced the "answer" here is particularly concerned with the English language itself. Your problem arises from the fact that you're assuming there's some concept of an "objective" value here (the "real" value, as opposed to the value ***claimed*** by way of compensation). Logically, it's possible to imagine such a thing, but a ***legal*** system wouldn't be likely to reference such an imprecise value.

Comment: Rather, how is it not clear that the value includes “… the goods or services” as well as “compensation, if any…”?

The numbers and values of rupees, crores and lakhs can’t matter. They are a distraction you need to forget entirely.

This is clearly not a question in English usage and meaning more than interpretation of a legal provision; rather vice versa - which is why in general, British law eschews commas in particular and would very likely have used your wording, "value of goods…” rather than the quoted "value of the goods…”

Comment: This is more a question of what the adjective "claimed" refers to - the legal context is broadly irrelevant. The Act limits the value that is claimed and the claim is calculated by adding  "(i) the value of the goods or services and (ii) compensation," with the concession that there might be no compensation. (Obviously, there has to be goods or services.)